# MySQL installation issues mysql-5.7.18-linux-glibc2.5-x86_64.tar

Tags: mysql

Image of problem

[image]

What's the problem?

Comment: view file log of mysql

Comment: can't you post the error message?

Comment: @bansi  I have shot the error message. Please click on it     enter image description here

Comment: Images are a *horrible* way to include code and error messages in a question.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors   and   https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-to-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question.  And "installation issues" and "what's the problem?" are close to useless as a title and a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `innodb_use_sys_malloc` system variable was removed in MySQL 5.7.

And that variable is being set, most likely, from the `my.cnf` file.

To fix this, remove the `innodb_use_sys_malloc` line from the `my.cnf` file. And then start MySQL server.

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_use_sys_malloc

Comment: think you It inspired me